# Groovy script to change all users to uppercase

Tags: magnolia

I'm trying to change all user names with in a magnolia application to uppercase since we are having case sensitivity issues with our login.

I wrote this groovy script, following an example used to reset passwords to "", to capture the users and change them uppercase but it appears the name property is not being set.

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Reset+all+passwords

```
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil
import info.magnolia.jcr.predicate.NodeTypePredicate
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeTypes
session = ctx.getJCRSession("users")
users = NodeUtil.collectAllChildren(session.getNode("/public"), new NodeTypePredicate(NodeTypes.User.NAME))

users.each() {
    changedName = it.name.toUpperCase();
    it.setProperty("name", changedName)
    it.save();
    println "1 " + changedName;
    println "2 " + it.name;
}
session.save();
```

When I'm checking it.name it is return how they are stored in the mangolia, and not as all uppercase and they are also not being changed in the security app when looking at the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil
import info.magnolia.jcr.predicate.NodeTypePredicate
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeTypes

session = ctx.getJCRSession("users")
users = NodeUtil.collectAllChildren(session.getNode("/admin"), new NodeTypePredicate(NodeTypes.User.NAME))

users.each() {
    name = it.name
    changedName = it.name.toUpperCase();
    it.setProperty("name", changedName)
    it.setProperty("jcrName", changedName)
    it.save()

    NodeUtil.renameNode(it, changedName)
    it.getNode("acl_users").getNodes().each { node ->
        newPath = node.getProperty("path").getString().replace(name, changedName)
        node.setProperty("path", newPath)
        node.save()
    }
}
session.save()
```

Hey, maybe this is what u are looking for. You need to change the Node name and the jcrName in my Version I iterate over the acl_users Node and change the path of each. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC there's 3 things you need to change.
`name` is one of them, then there's `jcrName` property and then you need to change the name of the node itself. At least if you want to see it in security app that way.
For the login itself, what you did should be already sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the setProperty method of [PropertyUtil](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/service/local/repositories/magnolia.public.releases/archive/info/magnolia/magnolia-core/6.0/magnolia-core-6.0-javadoc.jar/!/info/magnolia/jcr/util/PropertyUtil.html).
You have to extract all nodes that you need and then loops through them. Supposing that the variable **node** is the Node you want to change the name, do this:

```
String newName = StringUtils.upperCase(PropertyUtil.getString(node, "jcrName"));
PropertyUtil.setProperty(node, "jcrName", newName);
```

jcrName is the property you need to overwrite. Wrap the code into a try/catch block and here we go.

Hope it helps.